# How to store data that's being streamed to a live graph in plotly?

Tags: plotly

I am streaming data to a live graph in Plotly from a Particle Photon.

However, I'd like to save all the data that I'm streaming for future analysis.

Unfortunately, the streaming API only allows a certain number of points before the earliest point drops off. (I believe the max number of points allowed is 20,000.)

I've read from this Github [issue page](https://github.com/plotly/arduino-api/issues/20) that you can store data by making a REST call, but I'm still unsure about how to proceed.

Does anyone know a method or have any advice for me to develop a way to save live streaming data instead of using a middleman (like an RPi or PC) to store data before uploading data to plotly?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes fairly late, but hopefully others find it useful as well.

You can choose for a python application on your raspberry, which sends data to your stream and your database at the same time. You can use this tutorial to construct the stream using pyhton:
https://plot.ly/python/multiple-trace-streaming/#getting-set-up

It is rather simple to extend this script to send the data to a seperate database as well from the same while loop. I'm working on a similar thing, I will write some code as soon as I have it working.